# How to Deploy Rails App to AWS

Tags: ruby-on-rails, apache, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I am trying to host a Rails app in AWS cloud where I have an EC2 instance and apache and mysql . Here I have uploaded my app but I am unable to bind it with IP. For a testing I am using this blog post https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-deploy-a-rails-app-with-unicorn-and-nginx-on-ubuntu-14-04 as a reference .
When I am trying to run this command :

```
RAILS_ENV=production rails server --binding=server_public_IP
```

I am getting this error :

```
 /home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/socket.rb:206:in `bind': Cannot assign requested address - bind(2) for 52.24.103.139:3000 (Errno::EADDRNOTAVAIL)
```

Is there anyone help me understand what is this problem and how to deploy it on AWS apache .

Comment: Do you have required ports opened in aws settings?

Comment: like I have port 80 open my other domain work ok on domain

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In AWS the machine is not directly assigned the IP, i.e. it is routed using NAT. hence you can not use the public IP to start your rails server directly.

To start server just boot it without the binding parameter `rails s production`

Or you can use `0.0.0.0` to bind your server, this will start your rails on all the interfaces.

Tip: For production you should ideally server using some web server like nginx/apache using passenger/unicorn

Comment: Here I have installed apache2 and I am running few php site there and I want to run rails app with apache and want to check it on IP

Comment: When you are using apache with passenger, you won't need to explicitly start rails server, passenger will take care of it. You just have to setup a proper vhost.

What I understood is that you want to test your rails setup on server, for that you can not use the public IP for binding as that is not directly allocated to server.

Comment: @NilaySingh https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-deploy-a-rails-app-with-passenger-and-apache-on-ubuntu-14-04

Answer (score 0):

Looking from error it says it cannot bind with ipadd `52.24.103.139:3000`

What I would suggest it to open a  '`custom TCP port 3000`' and try running the same thing again.

May be your app is working on port `3000` not `80`.
Hope that helps.